# From West Africa to Tangier by ferries

Tags: ferries, africa

I'm looking for ferries from Banjul or Dakar to Tangier.
I'm going to West Africa in January 2020 by motorbike, but I wish to come back by ferry (and motorbike), but I did not find any solution throughout the internet...

Is there anybody, who knows possibility to come back by ferry or other alternatives?

Comment: [“Other alternatives”](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-niger-migrants/niger-smugglers-take-migrants-on-deadlier-saharan-routes-u-n-idUSKBN1AO25O).  Please stay safe.

Comment: You'll have to ship your bike back, though you could get lucky as a passenger on a freight ship.

Comment: Thanks for all! I hope if somebody has personal experience he or she share it with me... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few blogs about traveling in freight carriers, such as this one :
https://theplanetd.com/travelling-by-cargo-ship/
Some time ago, I had heard about the traject (travel? sorry, I'm a bit fear in English), but but can't find the url again. Please feel free to look for similar words. Hope success! :^)

Comment: Welcome to Travel! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanx a lot! I think it's very useful link to read the possibility of my journey :)))

Comment: traject probably means ferry in a language other than English, e.g. in Croatia the signs to the ferry were labeled "Trajekt"